# Fetch API cannot load [URL]. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404

Tags: javascript, http-request, request

Saudações !

Estou enfrentando o seguinte problema, faço uma requisição [POST] via Fetch API e "chamada" não conclui.

#### REQUISIÇÃO VIA Fetch API

```
const requestInfo = {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({ email:'jonathan@mail.com' , password:'123456', entity:'provider'}),
    headers: new Headers({'Content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'}),
};
fetch('http://localhost:4212/login',requestInfo)
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(sucess => console.log(sucess))
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }
```

#### RESPOSTA VIA Fetch API

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
O estranho é que requição do tipo [GET] funciona perfeitamente.

#### REQUISIÇÃO VIA POSTMAN

Via postman também funciona [GET/POST].
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#### HEADERS ENTREGUES

```
access-control-allow-credentials →true
access-control-allow-headers →Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Accept-Encoding, Content-Encoding, X-Auth-Token
access-control-allow-methods →POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE, PATCH
access-control-allow-origin →*
access-control-max-age →3600
cache-control →no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
content-encoding →gzip
content-type →application/json;charset=UTF-8
date →Thu, 27 Jul 2017 02:14:50 GMT
expires →0
pragma →no-cache
transfer-encoding →chunked
vary →Accept-Encoding
x-content-type-options →nosniff
x-frame-options →DENY
x-xss-protection →1; mode=block
```

Aguém sabe o que pode ser ?

Obrigado!

Comment: você usa algum framework para usar url sem extensão (`http://localhost:4212/login`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obrigado pela atenção

Resolvi o problema adicionado essa linha nas configurações de cors.

```
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
```

Se eu declarar somente POST/PUT não funciona. Tenho que esudar mais para descubrir. vlw

Answer (score 2):

Muitas vezes, Postman vai funcionar por que as regras de "Cross Origin Requests" não se aplicam. Se você está usando Express.js, você pode usar isso:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

O problema é que seu servidor não aceita requisição de um origem diferente. Use cors para permitir a seu cliente acessar seu servidor.

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção.